# How do I perform a "diff" on two Sources given a key using Apache Beam Python SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, apache-beam

I posed the question generically, because maybe it is a generic answer. But a specific example is comparing 2 BigQuery tables with the same schema, but potentially different data.  I want a diff, i.e. what was added, deleted, modified, with respect to a composite key, e.g. the first 2 columns.

```
Table A
C1  C2  C3
-----------
a   a   1
a   b   1
a   c   1

Table B     
C1  C2  C3  # Notes if comparing B to A
-------------------------------------
a   a   1   # No Change to the key a + a
a   b   2   # Key a + b Changed from 1 to 2
            # Deleted key a + c with value 1
a   d   1   # Added key a + d
```

I basically want to be able to make/report the comparison notes.
Or from a Beam perspective I may want to Just output up to 4 labeled PCollections: Unchanged, Changed, Added, Deleted.  How do I do this and what would the PCollections look like?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do here, basically, is join two tables and compare the result of that, right? You can look at [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287530/join-two-json-in-google-cloud-platform-with-dataflow/45290372#45290372), to see the two ways in which you can join two tables (Side inputs, or CoGroupByKey).

I'll also code a solution for your problem using `CoGroupByKey`. I'm writing the code in Python because I'm more familiar with the Python SDK, but you'd implement similar logic in Java:

```py
def make_kv_pair(x):
  """ Output the record with the x[0]+x[1] key added."""
  return ((x[0], x[1]), x)

table_a = (p | 'ReadTableA' >> beam.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(....))
            | 'SetKeysA' >> beam.Map(make_kv_pair)
table_b = (p | 'ReadTableB' >> beam.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(....))
            | 'SetKeysB' >> beam.Map(make_kv_pair))

joined_tables = ({'table_a': table_a, 'table_b': table_b}
                 | beam.CoGroupByKey())


output_types = ['changed', 'added', 'deleted', 'unchanged']
class FilterDoFn(beam.DoFn):
  def process((key, values)):
    table_a_value = list(values['table_a'])
    table_b_value = list(values['table_b'])
    if table_a_value == table_b_value:
      yield pvalue.TaggedOutput('unchanged', key)
    elif len(table_a_value) < len(table_b_value):
      yield pvalue.TaggedOutput('added', key)
    elif len(table_a_value) > len(table_b_value):
      yield pvalue.TaggedOutput('removed', key)
    elif table_a_value != table_b_value:
      yield pvalue.TaggedOutput('changed', key)

key_collections = (joined_tables 
                   | beam.ParDo(FilterDoFn()).with_outputs(*output_types))

# Now you can handle each output
key_collections.unchanged | WriteToText(...)
key_collections.changed | WriteToText(...)
key_collections.added | WriteToText(...)
key_collections.removed | WriteToText(...)
```