# Python Apache Beam - Join two Pcollections when the key of one collection is a subkey of the other collections key

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have a situation like this:

My first Pcollection is of the form:

```
(ID1): (status)
```

and my second collection is of the form:

`(ID1, ID2): (score1, score2)`

I need to join them so that I have

```
(ID1, ID2): (score1, score2, status)
```

i.e. I want to join them on `ID1` independent of `ID2`. How would I go about this? Should I recast my second collection to

```
(ID1): (ID2, score1, score2)
```

first and then join them with CoGroupByKey() ? If so, how do I recast the key/value so that one part of the key is moved to the value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I solved it, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287530/join-two-json-in-google-cloud-platform-with-dataflow/45290372#45290372
Just use a simple beam.Map to rewrite to ID1: (ID2, score1, score2) , join, then beam.Map again to get back to (ID1, ID2): (score1, score2, status)

Comment: I am having trouble figuring my solution out at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57387749/join-2-json-inputs-linked-by-primary-key/57388411?noredirect=1#comment101264574_57388411

Comment: Are you able to answer your own question so I have another reference to my question? Cheers

Comment: @HWong Did you see the reply I wrote? It has a link to another question that I used to solve it. Also my comment shows how I did it, though I can't remember exactly how now

Comment: Hi @digestivee yes I saw, but I also commented on that link. I don't know what are the 2 variables for in the answer of that link. It is undefined..

Comment: What variables? @HWong
Departments and Employees are the data you are trying to join. k and v are just variable names where we input that data

Comment: 'join_dict'- what variable is that ? And 'employee'